# batch or vbs forced BSOD

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, process

Is there a way is batch or vbs to force the blue screen of death to appear, or a forced crash.  This can happen from stopping the process "csrss.exe" but it wont close via simple batch or vbs script. How can this be done?

Comment: who wants to kill a machine?? Years ago there was a "fun-program" that showed a Screenshot of a BlueScreen. Perhaps this is the way to go for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try [NotMyFault](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/NotMyFault.zip) by Sysinternals.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want this, but...

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im wininit.exe
pause
```

You might need to set this to run as an Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a .bat file with `%0|%0` inside, your computer starts to use a lot of memory and after several minutes, is restarted.

`%0` is the name of the currently executing batch file. A batch file that simply does:

```
%0|%0
```

Is going to recursively execute itself forever, quickly creating many processes and slowing the system down.

It's a logic bomb, it keeps recreating itself and takes up all your CPU resources. It overloads your computer with too many processes and it forces it to shut down. If you make a batch file with this in it and start it you can end it using taskmgr. You have to do this pretty quickly or your computer will be to slow to do anything.

This is known as a fork bomb.
It keeps splitting itself until there is no option but to restart the system.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb

This is not a bug in windows, it is just a very stupid thing to do in a batch file. so if you want to test it, you must save your work before.

Answer (score 0):

```
set ramconsumer = createobject("wscript.shell")
do
ramconsumer.run wscript.scriptname
loop
```

not shure why you need it but here it is a vbs version